# How to write a test for a custom action on a viewset in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django, and Django Rest Framework.

I would like to know how to go about testing custom actions. For example, assume we have the following code from the DRF tutorials

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post', 'put'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How would I go about calling this view in a test in DRF.

```
def test_password_set(self):
    user = User.objects.create(name="Joe")
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request_url = f'users/{user.id}/set_password/'
    request = factory.post(request_url)

    view = UserViewSet.as_view({'put': 'update'})
    response = view(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

That code gives me the error below

```
AssertionError: 405 != 200
```

which means that the given method is not allowed.

Could anyone help me figure out what the error could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a mistake here

```
request = factory.post(request_url)
```

It should be `put`:

```
request = factory.put(request_url)
```

And also, you should add the data into the request body. In this line, you're trying to get `data` from the request object.

```
serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
```

This data depends on the `PasswordSerializer`; But for example, it should be something like this (it should contain all parameters of the serializer):

```
request = factory.put(request_url, {'password': 'sTr0ngPass'})
```